# Firedac - Best to open a query just to add records

Tags: delphi, firedac

When I want to create a FDQuery just to add records, is there a way to build/open/create the FDQuery  in a way that I can actually do Inserts and Appends, without having to load the current info in the DB?

I find myself doing this horrible thing, where I put an impossible filter, so that I load the metadata but i dont actually load anything from the DB :/

```
    fQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 1=2';
```

But with all firedac possibilities surely there is a better way than this ...

So, is there a way to open a FDQuery with the metadata but not the data itself?
(If you are going to suggest the FDTable instead, please tell me if it has a better performance and why)

Comment: What DB manager are you using?

Comment: What's stopping you just making your SQL.Text being an INSERT statement?  Come to that, what's stopping you using SELECT to open the table and then using the FDQuery's Insert method  (or InsertRecord)?

Comment: MartynA, in this case, just the fact that i have MSSQL or FIrebird DB's connected to the software and i want Firedac to handle the types (dates, blobs,etc...) and query syntax.

Comment: I thought I understood you the first time but after your comment I'm lost,  **Do you want to get only the structure of a table from the db (on your TDataGrid or similar) then append/insert to it?** or what?

Comment: Could use a `TFDTable` and set the TableName property? Creates the SQL for you.

Comment: Ok, well what's stopping you getting the metadata info as explained here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Querying_Metadata_(FireDAC).  You can check SQL syntax by calling Prepare on your dataset.

Comment: `WHERE 1=2` is (at least for Firebird mentioned in comments) a wrong choice - it performs full natural scan of a table.

Comment: BrakNicku, thats why im asking for an alternative :)

Comment: Nasreddine Galfout, Yes, I want to get the structure so that i use .Append; FieldByName; Post; statements.

Comment: If you want (for whatever reason) a query returning no rows in Firebird you can use for example `WHERE name_of_primary_key is NULL`.

Comment: BrakNicku is that not that same as i have? an impossible WHERE to return no rows... all i really want is a property in the FDQuery object (probably the fetch options) that allows me to do that WITHOUT the WHERE clause...

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues No, it is not the same - execution plans are different, [an example with big table](https://i.imgur.com/BqrSuPt.png). PS. If you want to have someone notified about your comment add `@` before the name.

Comment: Having a FD query object property is not enough as long as such property modified the SQL command you execute. FireDAC is a client and even if you fetch the resultset manually or limit number of tuples (which is possible), it can be the DBMS who will do the hardest work (e.g. that full table scan).